# Use of index on Guid column

Tags: sql-server, database-indexes

What is the use of having an index on a Guid column in SQL Server? Indexes sort the rows, as per my knowledge. If Guids are randomly generated and are not sorted how do indexes work on them?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Indexes sort the columns` ... indexes make it easier for the database to find _rows_, not columns.  The guid index you describe might help in certain queries.

Comment: I meant to say index sort the rows for that particular column

Comment: Indexes are stored separately from source table. They don't sort columns in tables.

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have a telephone book with `(person,number)` pairs. Is there any reason to sort the book by `number`? Obviously not: you will never ask queries which search for persons having number between number1 and number2. **BUT**: you might want to search for the owner of a particular number. And indexing the `number` is the only efficient way to do this.

Likewise, indexing a GUID helps you quickly identify the **unique** tuple with this value. And an index is necessary for this.